# generate two variables while using split

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this

```
test/something/else
```

I would like to generate two variables

```
first = test
second = something/else
```

I tried with

```
const [first, ...second] = "test/something/else".split("/");
```

and it gives me the right value for **first** but for **second** it's an array. So I have to join the array to get the value I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regular expression to match a (single) `/` followed by anything, so that the result is the 2 strings you want:

```js
const str = 'test/something/else';
const [, first, second] = str.match(/([^/]+)\/(.*)/);
console.log(first);
console.log(second);
```

If you had to use `split`, and you don't want the extra array, you can do something similar by putting the second part into a capture group:

```js
const str = 'test/something/else';
const [first, second] = str.split(/\/(.*)/);
console.log(first);
console.log(second);
```

Comment: interesting. what's the , at the beginning ? first time I see it :)

Comment: You don't have to define a variable when destructuring. `const [, foo] = arr` is like `const foo = arr[1]`. Since you don't care about the full match, only the capture group(s), the first element is omitted while destructuring.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, the idiomatic built-in command to do this is to `.split()` and then `.join(‘’)` the tail elements.

It may be (very slightly) faster to check for the index and slice the string with that, something like

```js
function splitAt(str, delimiter) {
  const idx = str.indexOf(delimiter);
  const head = str.slice(0, idx);
  const tail = str.slice(idx);
  return [head, tail];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution is simple, we should take 2 variables, in one variable assign the string which includes '/' then in another variable assign split method split(//(.*)/) with expresion and console log it**

```
var str = "how r u?/kkk/jj";
const [first, second] = str.split(/\/(.*)/);
console.log(first);
console.log(second);
```

split method break the string and assign em to arrays. The string will be break after '/' and whenever console log the item, the broken string will be displayed.